# How to fix "expected enum QueryRequest, found enum QueryRequest" when using near-json-rpc and near-primitives?

Tags: rust, enums, rpc, nearprotocol

I am trying to use [near-json-rpc](https://docs.rs/near-jsonrpc-client/latest/near_jsonrpc_client/) and when I build the [`RpcQueryRequest`](https://docs.rs/near-jsonrpc-client/latest/near_jsonrpc_client/methods/query/struct.RpcQueryRequest.html) I get the following errors related to the [near-primitives](https://docs.rs/near-primitives/latest/near_primitives/) types:

```
expected enum near_primitives::types::BlockReference, found enum BlockReference
expected enum near_primitives::views::QueryRequest, found enum QueryRequest
```

The `BlockReference` and `QueryRequest` enums are imported. Here is the code that builds the request:

```
use near_primitives::types::Finality::DoomSlug;
use near_primitives::types::BlockReference::Finality;
use near_primitives::views::QueryRequest::ViewAccount;

...

let request = ViewAccount {
    account_id: "address.near".parse().unwrap()
};

let block_reference = Finality(DoomSlug);

let status_request = RpcQueryRequest {
    block_reference,
    request
};
```

The errors are generated in the last 3 lines when creating `status_request`, using the `block_reference` and `request` variables.

Here are my dependencies inside Cargo.toml:

```toml
[dependencies]
near-jsonrpc-client = "0.3.0"
futures = "0.3.24"
tokio = { version = "1.21.1", features = ["full"] }
near-primitives = "0.15.0"
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Almost definitely a version incompatibility. Can you include your dependencies from `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: Hello, I edited the question and added the dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using near-primitives *version 0.15*, but near-jsonrpc-client version 0.3 depends on near-primitives *version 0.12*. Those two are incompatible so using one version's types in place of another won't work.

You should downgrade your dependency on near-primitives to match:

```toml
near-primitives = "0.12.0"
```